# manipulating divisible numbers?

Tags: numbers, number-theory

if you have an integer array n and you want to check if n[i] divisible by any of these numbers for example: 2,3,5.

all possible results:

```
1) n[i] is divisible by 2 only
2) n[i] is divisible by 3 only
3) n[i] is divisible by 5 only
4) n[i] is divisible by 2 and 3
5) n[i] is divisible by 3 and 5
6) n[i] is divisible by 2 and 5
7) n[i] is divisible by 2, 3 and 5
```

if you decide only to know the first 3 results, is there a method to derive the rest of results from it ?

because if the numbers to check the divisibility against them where many numbers the possible results will be exponentially many results too.

for example i have x numbers from the array and i know how many of them are divisible by 2 and how many are divisible by 3 and how many are divisible by 5, but i want to know for example how many are divisible by 2 or 3 (union), if i added the count of numbers divisible by 2 to the count of numbers divisible by 3 many numbers will be duplicated (the intersection which have a set divisible by both 2 and 3).

so is there a way to know this intersection from the only information that i have (the information: count of numbers divisible by 2, and count of numbers divisible by 3, and count of numbers divisible by 5) ?

Answer (score 0):

No. For example, [2,3,4,9,5] and [2,3,6,5,7] both have the same number of entries divisible by 2,3, and 5, but differ as to the number of entries divisible by 6.

**On edit**. Here is an even simpler example: [2, 5, 6] vs. [2, 3, 10]. Both of these have 2 even numbers, 1 multiple of 3, and 1 multiple of 5, but they differ as to the number of elements divisible by 6 = 2*3 and the number of elements divisible by 10 = 2*5.